# raspberry pi python 3 update and upgrading error cant update anything

Tags: python, pi

imtrying to update my raspberry pi 3b but i get this error.i can not update anythingt because of this error.

File "usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in 
from pkg_resouces import load_entry_point
File"usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_recourses/**init**.py", line
117
f"{v} is an invalid version and will not be supported in "
^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version of `pip` that you are using contains [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

These are only supported in Python 3.6 and later.
So I'd suggest that you update your raspberry pi:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If that doesn't provide a recent enough version, you will have to update to a newer raspbian OS version.
Look on the raspberry Pi website to see how to download and write a newer OS version to an SD-card.